# How I can solve this error message from command line when I run macs2

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a problem when I try to run macs2 from my command line, using the follow code: 
macs2 callpeak -t target.BAM -c control.bam -f BAM -g hs -n test -B -q 0.01

I have this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projas/MACS2-2.1.1.20160309/bin/macs2", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/projas/MACS2-2.1.1.20160309/bin/macs2", line 56, in main
    from MACS2.callpeak_cmd import run
  File "/home/projas/MACS2-2.1.1.20160309/MACS2/callpeak_cmd.py", line 31, in <module>
    from MACS2.OptValidator import opt_validate
  File "/home/projas/MACS2-2.1.1.20160309/MACS2/OptValidator.py", line 204
    options.argtxt += "# Using a custom scaling factor: %.2e\n" % (options.ratio)
                                                                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

any idea ?

Comment: As mentioned in the stacktrace, you are mixing tabs and spaces. Figure out where you are doing that and make it consistent

Comment: The OP is using a bioinformatics library called `MACS2` which seems to be drawing the error. I used MACS2 and have never gotten that error. I would post as an issue to https://github.com/taoliu/MACS/issues